# how to store position of a player as a variable?(minecraft java)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a project in which i need position of a player at any tick. i used the command:

```
data get entity player_name Pos[0]

data get entity player_name Pos[1]

data get entity player_name Pos[2]
```

but i want them to be stored as variables. how can i do that. And also if possible tell me how to display variables in scoreboard

this is not the solution of my problem
[Minecraft using player score as a variable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/263855/minecraft-using-player-score-as-a-variable)
[How can I set a player's scoreboard score to a player's coordinates [1.15.2]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372087/how-can-i-set-a-players-scoreboard-score-to-a-players-coordinates-1-15-2)
this is a duplicate suggested but this question dosent deals with storage in a variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set a player's scoreboard score to a player's coordinates \[1.15.2\]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372087/how-can-i-set-a-players-scoreboard-score-to-a-players-coordinates-1-15-2)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 anything that can store and change in my .mcfunction. Like in other programming language we can declare like position_z=data get entity player_name Pos[2].All I am asking is how do i assign position_z to that value. Scoreboards have their limitations and can't do that effectively

Comment: and mess with that value. Which can't be done in scoreboards

Comment: What do you need to do to "mess with" a value? Perhaps you just aren't using scoreboards effectively. Are you just doing basic assignment and basic arithmetic?

Comment: `mcfunction` is not a programming language and doesn't support things such as variables. The linked questions should enable what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok thank you @Schism can you please tell me if not .mcfunction will solve my problem then can tell me an alternative. like .json() which will store that data for me